# How to encode when u have multiple categories in a column

Tags: python, pandas, encoding

My data frame looks like this

[image]

Pandas data frame with multiple categorical variables for a user

I made sure there are no duplicates in it. I want to encode it and I want my final output like this

[image]

I tried using pandas dummies directly but I am not getting the desired result.
Can anyone help me through this??

Comment: Your dataframe is an image, please code that can be copied into an editor

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, your `user` is empty and everything is on `name`. If that's the case, you can

```
pd.pivot_table(df, index=df.name.str[0], columns=df.name.str[1:].values, aggfunc='count').fillna(0)
```

Comment: @nixon for digits from 9o n, just replace `[1]` with `[1:]`

Comment: Sorry for that table but the user is not empty and the user represents number and the name represents alphabets. Anyways helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can split each row in `name` using `r'(\d+)'` to separate digits from letters, and use [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
d = pd.DataFrame(df.name.str.split(r'(\d+)').values.tolist())
pd.crosstab(columns=d[2], index=d[1], values=d[1], aggfunc='count')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the the `str` accessor `get_dummies` with `groupby` `user` column:

```
df.name.str.get_dummies().groupby(df.user).sum()
```

#### Example

Given your sample DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user': [1]*4 + [2]*4 + [3]*3,
                   'name': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']*2 + ['d', 'e', 'f']})

df_dummies = df.name.str.get_dummies().groupby(df.user).sum()
print(df_dummies)
```

[out]

```
      a  b  c  d  e  f
user                  
1     1  1  1  1  0  0
2     1  1  1  1  0  0
3     0  0  0  1  1  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following dataframe:

```
   user name
0     1    a
1     1    b
2     1    c
3     1    d
4     2    a
5     2    b
6     2    c
7     3    d
8     3    e
9     3    f
```

You could [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) user and then use [get_dummmies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
import pandas as pd

# create data-frame
data = [[1, 'a'], [1, 'b'], [1, 'c'], [1, 'd'], [2, 'a'],
        [2, 'b'], [2, 'c'], [3, 'd'], [3, 'e'], [3, 'f']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['user', 'name'])

# group and get_dummies
grouped = df.groupby('user')['name'].apply(lambda x: '|'.join(x))
print(grouped.str.get_dummies())
```

**Output**

```
      a  b  c  d  e  f
user                  
1     1  1  1  1  0  0
2     1  1  1  0  0  0
3     0  0  0  1  1  1
```

As a side-note, you can do it all in one line:

```
result = df.groupby('user')['name'].apply(lambda x: '|'.join(x)).str.get_dummies()
```